# How to make Windows roaming profile with Linux

Tags: linux, windows, roaming-profile

I have 2 labs with 20 computers each of them. All the computers are running Windows XP Pro and the user profile is loaded from a SunOS system (Solaris 8).

No matter which PC the user will use, he just enters his user and pass and the profile is loaded.

Because the system is very old and it is customized and configure from someone else I can not update it because it may never start again or it may not work.

So, can I do the same with Linux (doesn't matter which distro)?

What do I need to make it work (LDAP,Samba...)?

Comment: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/samba-pdc.html

Comment: Yes,good point!

Answer (score 0):

If the SunOS server is the only server in the equation, it's probably configured using SAMBA as a PDC and has the user profiles shared from it as well. The procedure to do this is [documented](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/samba-pdc.html), but not ideal. If you can use a Windows Server instead of a Linux server, you'll have many more features. SAMBA4 adds a lot of options, but it's still nowhere near feature competitive with full-blown AD.